# Does Han Solo know what is going to happen when he encounters Kylo Ren on the bridge?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, han-solo

In The Force Awakens, on the bridge, it's not clear to me if Han goes into his confrontation with Kylo Ren expecting the outcome, e.g.

> that his son will kill him.

much less expecting to help Kylo Ren complete his task. If that's the case, I don't understand why things needed to work out the way they did.

- Why does Kylo Ren have to go through with it if he's conflicted
- Why would he need Han's help?
- What obligation is holding him to completing this task?
- Why not just decide to turn to the light?

Comment: This question is quite a spoiler! Could you refrase it somehow. Two mayor spoiler before you even read the tags is maybe too much...

Comment: yes, it was in the script

Comment: I have rephrased the title, I did not know spoilers were off limits. At what point aren't they? 2-3 months post release?

Comment: If Han knows then that he is helping him to his own death, why not just make a stronger argument for coming back to the light? Why does Han believe that he needs to go through with it? Why not just convince him to become good, he's obviously conflicted.

Comment: As a first time poster, I can see why you might want to change the title of a post to avoid a spoiler, although as some point the statute of limitation runs out. However, I see no point in editing the content of a post. If someone clicks through to a post about The Force Awakens, they should be expecting to get spoiled.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield the only post on the first page of Active and Hot on meta is this one: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/how-to-avoid-star-wars-spoilers and it makes no mention of the content of post. In fact, the most upvoted answer in meta is to ignore the force-awakens tag because spoilers are likely.

Comment: We have [no moratorium on spoilers](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1561/5184), and policy is to [avoid spoilers in titles when possible](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6855/5184), *especially* when it comes to character deaths. This is on top of our [general spoiler policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/968/5184).

Comment: That is to say, I'd hardly call the meta posts extensively documented. If meta posts such as this are important, they should be featured.

Comment: featured meta posts are supposed to be short-lived -- there's only a small number that you can "feature" at a time; we are working to improve the visibility of "policy/FAQ" questions, though, so your point there is valid.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. The only reason I questioned all of this is because I think redacting content actually takes away from the dialogue on my question (i.e. makes the dialogue impossible without revealing the plot). I always want to try to respect the rules and culture of new communities I join, when those rules make sense. When they don't however, I think they're always worth revisiting.

Answer (score 9):

No, there's no indication that Han knew or expected the outcome he got, let alone that he was intending to help Kylo Ren do it. Han confronted Kylo because that's what Leia asked him to do:

> go out and bring their son back.

I'm sure Han knew he was talking a risk, but he seemed to genuinely believe he could turn Kylo away from the Dark Side, or at the very least, stall his progress and get him to reconsider his actions.

For Kylo's part, his conflict and the ultimate obligation he felt to go through with

> killing his father

were laid out in a number of earlier scenes, including the initial exchange with Snoke when Kylo first learns that Han Solo is back in the picture, and later Kylo's monlogue with the Vader mask.  Kylo is feeling conflicted over his decision to turn to the Dark -- not because he regrets it or wants to change it, but because he can't seem to get rid of the nagging "tug" pulling him back to the Light. He sincerely wants to obey Snoke and do what he feels is the "right" thing, but there's a small part of him that keeps telling him to repent.

When Kylo and Han face off, that conflict is brought up to the surface. Kylo now seems to recognize that

> his father's presence in his life

is one of the key things holding him back from fully committing to the Dark Side, and he wants to eliminate that obstacle. The struggle on the bridge was, seemingly, the last ditch effort by his Light side to pull him back from the brink, which obviously didn't work.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last sentence. Getting rid of Han means that Kilo will have no body to scapegoat. It does not ease the conflict within him.

Comment: well, technically there's still Leia but I suspect the next movie will put him in direct conflict with Luke and Rey.

Comment: I remember an answer to one of my questions quotes the script or novelisation that Kylo did think this course of action will resolve the conflict within him and complete his transition to darkness. But after the deed, it turns out he's only more conflicted than ever. Expectations vs reality, I suppose.

Comment: Snoke basically *tells* Kylo that Han is the thing standing in his way. I think Kylo is clearly being portrayed as more of a "lost kid looking up to the wrong guy" than, e.g. Vader was. So it makes sense that he'd assume his master knew what he was talking about.

Answer (score 3):

No, Han doesn't know that Kylo will kill him (but I'm sure he was expecting the risk)

Han comes to the bridge in attempt to take Kylo home, to mend the fences. Kylo shows (or feigns) the sympathy, then attempts (or just pretends to) give the sword to Han, who tries to take it from him... and then Kylo runs him through, embracing the dark side.

It didn't happen because Kylo needed help killing his father, it happened because Kylo rejected Han's attempt to pull him to the light side.

Comment: Not sure I buy that Kylo's conflicted and emotional exchange was feigned. He could have easily killed him without the song and dance then. More plausible to me would be that he was conflicted and then decided to embrace the dark side again.

Comment: You're right, it s bit more ambiguous. I've changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

In the moment that it happens, there is no evidence to suggest that he was expecting the outcome in any way. Whether Kylo is genuinely torn, or whether he is feigning it, Han has no reason to believe that at that particular time point in time, the subsequent events will happen.

If you go back in time to when he makes the choice to reveal himself, at that point he would likely have been aware of the risk, and the exchanges with Leia earlier would suggest that even if he felt it was more likely than not that his attempt would fail, he felt obliged to go through with it.

The lighting of the scene (shadow obscuring the light) is specifically meant to represent the pull of the Light, and the switch back to the Dark side, for whatever you want to read into that.