# Why didn't Han Solo stop Kylo Ren? (Spoilers)

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren, han-solo

So in Star Wars: The Force Awakens,

> Han Solo dies, killed by his own son, Kylo Ren.

But there's something that's been bugging me about that.

> Why didn't Han stop Kylo Ren (aka Ben) from killing him?

[image: Kylo Ren handing his lightsaber to Han Solo]

Here is the scene right after Kylo Ren says that he knows what he needs to do, but he needs his (Han's) help, and he hands Han his lightsaber, and drops his mask on the bridge. The thing is, as you can see in the picture, he holds the lightsaber horizontally, with the live end pointing to his right (Han's left). And Han has a hand on the weapon as well. So, practically, he would feel is Ren tried to turn the saber to the side, or to point it towards Han.

Ok, I'd understand if Han had died because Ren drove the 'sidebar' of his lightsaber through him. Eventhough Han had spent a lot of time around Luke, and was familiar with the lightsaber, Luke's lightsaber didn't have the sidebars. Han has probably seen Ren's unique lightsaber before, but I could accept that he forgot about the sidebars. This is ***if*** Ren had stabbed Han with the sidebar.

[image: Kylo Ren stabs Han Solo]

But in this scene, it's pretty obvious that Ren did *not* stab Han with the sidebar, but with the full length of the lightsaber. Which means that he must have turned it from facing his right to facing his front. And ***Han had his hand still on the lightsaber!*** So he must have felt Ren turning it around to face him.

Why didn't Han stop Ren killing him? If he was that much older and weaker than Ren and couldn't physically stop him, why didn't he just jump out of the way?

EDIT: In [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116960), it was asked if Han knew Ren was going to kill him. But that question addresses what was going through his mind as he confronted Ren solo (pun intended). My question is asking why he ***did*** let Ren kill him. It's as if he not only knew Ren was going to kill him, but he *wanted it*. Why?

Comment: My guess is that as a parent he wanted to give his son a chance to redeem himself, which required that he put some (alas misplaced) trust in him and  deliberately let his guard slip.

Comment: Kylo could use force to turn the saber, and Han was not able to resist this

Comment: Come on, don't go telling the whole world. That was supposed to be a secret!

Answer (score 2):

**Han just does not see what is coming.**

If you look at it shot by shot you can see that Kylo Ren was lowering the lightsaber and at the same time was pointing it in the direction of Han Solo. This all seems to be a harmless action by Kylo Ren, until he **suddenly** turns the lightsaber on and in doing so pierces through the body of Han Solo.

This is the very first frame after we see a close up of Han Solo and Kylo Ren holding the lightsaber together. It then cuts to Rey and then to this frame below. You can just see where Han Solo's hand is. It is slightly stretched out towards Kylo Ren.

[image]

The first frame shows that Han Solo was not really holding the saber with much force at this point.

[image]

The next shows the start of Ren turning on the saber, you can see Han still has not moved and is not expecting what is coming next.

[image]

Still Han does not move and the saber is well on its way into Han.

[image]

In the final frame Han still has not moved his hand.

[image]

**So from what I can see is that Han just did not see it coming.**

Out of universe, [J.J. Abrams](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/21/jj-abrams-kylo-ren-shocking-act-star-wars-force-awakens) stated,

> Long before we had this title, the idea of The Force Awakens was that
>   this would become the evolution of not just a hero, but a villain.
>   Star Wars had the greatest villain in cinema history. So, how you
>   bring a new villain into that world is a very tricky thing. We knew we
>   needed to do something fucking bold. The only reason why Kylo Ren has
>   any hope of being a worthy successor is because we lose one of the
>   most beloved characters.

So it was essentially a way to make Kylo Ren more of a villain.